# Programmatically Ensuring YouTube API Live Streams Update to 'Completed' Status

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm encountering a challenge with the YouTube Data API where live stream broadcasts don't update to 'completed' after concluding, despite thorough testing and adherence to scheduled times. Instead, the status reverts to 'created' post-stream. This issue persists even after generating 'Live Replay' videos, indicating the streams concluded as expected.

Issue Details:

I've been using the YouTube Data API for scheduling and managing live streams. My process involves:

Setting precise start and end times for each event.
Initiating and concluding an RTMP feed at these exact times, expecting this to signal stream completion.
Post-stream, 'Live Replay' videos are generated correctly, yet the original broadcast status reverts to 'created.'

This behavior impacts my ability to manage stream keys and maintain consistent video ID management for 'Live Replay' videos, crucial for my operations.

Specific Challenge:

The API's enableAutoStart and enableAutoStop settings are configured to True, aiming to mimic the "Auto Stop" feature's behavior. However, the expected status transition to 'completed' doesn't occur.

My script setup involves converting scheduled times to UTC to account for time zone differences and signaling stream conclusion through RTMP feed termination at the scheduled end time. Despite this, the status issue persists.

Question:

Has anyone successfully implemented a workflow or found API calls/processes within the YouTube Data API that ensure a live stream automatically transitions to 'completed' status after the scheduled end time? I'm looking for a solution or workaround that achieves the expected outcome similar to manually using the "Auto-stop" feature in YouTube Studio.

Any insights or suggestions on alternative API calls or processes that could help resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.